# Set SelectedItem for UWP ComboBox

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

A UWP ComboBox ItemsSource displays correctly but the SelectedItem is not selected in the list. Why is that so?

The XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="FooComboBox" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foos}" 
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foo,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ChangeTypeConverter}}"/>
```

`ChangeTypeConverter` comes from `Template10`

`Foos` and the value of the property `Foo` are set in the ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{    
    Foo _Foo = default(Foo);
    public Foo Foo { get { return _Foo; } set { Set(ref _Foo, value); } }
    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>(FooService.GetFoos());
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Foo = FooService.GetDefaultFoo();
```

A Foo looks like this

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid FooId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string FooCode { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FooCode;
    }
}
```

Yet although `FooComboBox` correctly renders the list of `Foos`, the  `SelectedItem` is not set to the current value of the property `Foo`. Why is that so?

Comment: Does GetDefaultFoo() return an instance that's actually in Foos? Ie, verify that `Foos.Contains(Foo) == true`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Henk Holterman. I can see `Foo` is in `Foo's` ... same `FooId` and `FooCode`, however `Foos.Contains(Foo)` returns `false`. Scratching my head wondering why that might be?

Comment: I guess that GetDefaultFoo() gets the values from the same source (Db) and then creates it's own instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn the comments into an answer,

The SelectedItem should be an actual item inside the ItemsSource list, as determined by the Equals() method. In your case it was a separate instance and although it had the same Id it wasn't considered Equal.

There are several ways to solve this, perhaps the one that will solve similar issues down the road is to override Equals:

```
public class Foo
{
    ...
    // untested
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo other = obj as Foo;
        return FooId.Equals(other?.FooId);
    }
}
```

but this has implications for the rest of your app. I would only consider using this to solve a SelectedItem issue when Foo is a ViewModel.

---

The other solution is to go find the actual item in the source list:

```
public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos = ...;
public ViewModel()
{
   var d = FooService.GetDefaultFoo();
   Foo = Foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FooId == d.FooId);    
}
```

Comment: This is a terrific solution for this problem.